# Regex - Split up URL path and place into variables

Tags: regex

I'm really bad at regular expressions. I have a url like `/this%20is%20part%20one/and%20part%20two` and I need to:

**1)** Replace all the `%20`'s with *spaces* so it's a normal looking string

**2)** Store each part away into it's own variable

In the end, var1 should have `this is part one` and var2 should have `and part two`

I made a picture for you:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Javascript

```js
var re =/%20/g;
var testString = '/this%20is%20part%20one/and%20part%20two';
var splitString= testString.replace(re,' ').split('/')
var var1= splitString[1];
var var2= splitString[2];
console.log('var1:',capitalizeFirstLetters(var1));
console.log('var2:',capitalizeFirstLetters(var2));

function capitalizeFirstLetters(str){
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/^\w|\s\w/g, function (letter) {
      return letter.toUpperCase();
  })
}
```

Comment: This works great! Quick question, how would I capitalize the first letter of each word in splitString[1] and splitString[2]?

Comment: Edited the answer to capitalize the first letters

Comment: Glad it helped, Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` you can do:

```
url="/this%20is%20part%20one/and%20part%20two"
var1=$(sed 's/%20/ /g' <<< $url | cut -d'/' -f2)
var2=$(sed 's/%20/ /g' <<< $url | cut -d'/' -f3)
```

Output:

```
>echo $va1
this is part one
>echo $var2
and part two
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a regex for this? Seem like using a hammer to hit a fly. You should be able to:

1. Do a global `.replace()` for `%20` to `' '`.
2. Explode that string with `/` as a delimiter.

For example:

```
let url  = '/this%20is%20part%20one/and%20part%20two';

url = url.replace( /%20/g, ' ', url ); //url = "/this is part one/and part two"
url = url.split('/'); //url = ["", "this is part one", "and part two"]
```

This will let you use array indices: `url[1]` and `url[2]` (`url[0]` is blank from the first `/` that was captured). If you don't want to use an indexed array however, suited to your example:

```
var1 = var2 = '';

for( i = 0, n = 1; i < url.length; ++i ){
    if( url[i].length > 0 ){
        window['var' + n++] = url[i];
    }
}

console.log(
    var1, // "this is part one"
    var2  // "and part two"
);
```